# StencilJS Navigates pages not rendering correctly in navigated page

Tags: stenciljs

I'm building an app with StencilJS and when I navigate to another page, the new page doesn't render correctly. The toolbar color doesn't get set correctly and the page doesn't render page content like it does on the home page (padding, etc.).

Here's the render method for the about page (that isn't rendering correctly).

```
 render() {
    return [
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
          <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button defaultHref="/" />
          </ion-buttons>
          <ion-title>About</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>,

      <ion-content class="ion-padding">
        <p>
          Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork pork chop burgdoggen, swine spare ribs capicola andouille shankle. Buffalo landjaeger meatball chislic tenderloin. Meatloaf capicola ham hock, kevin biltong cow ground round shankle. Chislic sausage picanha porchetta doner corned beef. Andouille prosciutto short loin alcatra landjaeger capicola rump buffalo. Tri-tip kielbasa beef pork belly, cow turducken bresaola.
        </p>
        <p>
          Doner biltong jerky flank pancetta. Andouille pork chop shankle jerky meatloaf. Drumstick alcatra ham hock swine venison turkey capicola bresaola jowl buffalo kevin cow hamburger. Biltong burgdoggen pig shank shoulder. Cupim chicken doner sirloin alcatra strip steak. Jowl pork t-bone, ham burgdoggen venison ball tip swine ham hock biltong ground round tri-tip kevin bacon.
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    ];
  }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? In regular Ionic/Angular the pages all look the same as you navigate between them and I've never been unable to set the header color.

[image]

Comment: What seems to be happening is the new page isn't getting any styling. Like it can't see the css file.

Comment: Which versions (Ionic/Stencil) are you using? Are you using the Ionic router? What happens when you visit that page directly? Are there any messages in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the Ionic Forums: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-a-stenciljs-project-with-electron-for-capacitor/171219/4